# jQuery - $(window).scroll(function() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where I want to move the scroll down if it is at the top. But nothing happens, before and after the function value is still 0.
This is the code:

```
scrollDrawer = function () {
      if (drawerIsUp) {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());


        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() < 92 ) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".middle").offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());

    function winScroll() {
       drawerDiv.style.top = (drawerDiv.offset + window.pageYOffset) + "px";
    }

  }
}
```

**Updated**

```
console.log($(window).scrollTop());

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ( $("html,body").scrollTop() < 92 && $("html,body").scrollTop() > 0) {
                $("html,body").scrollTop(800)
            }
        });

        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
```

I have updated the code and modifed it by applying suggestions from the answers, but still the scroll doesn't get relocated. I wonder if that is maybe since when the page opens it is already at top 0, and I need to relocate it immediately without scrolling from the user in the first place.

Html:

```
          <div id="app">
            <div id="bg">
            </div>

              @section('topBar')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.top-bar')
              @show
            <div id="main-section">
              @section('header')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.header')
              @show

              @section('carousel')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['function' => 'drawer', 'carouselPadding' => ''])
              @show
            </div>

            <div id="drawer">
              <div id="magazine-detail">
              </div>
              <div id="magazine-detail-carousel">
                @section('magazine-detail-carousel')
                  @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['function' => 'magazineDetail', 'carouselPadding' => 'carouselPadding'])
                @show
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-section {
  height: calc(100vh - 92px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top:77px;
}

#drawer {
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100vh;
  height: calc(100vh - 92px);
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

On click div `drawer` that is first not visible since it is below the vh, goes over the top of the `main-section` all the way up to where the `top-bar` starts. This is the animation:

```
$('#drawer').animate({
      top: 92
    }, 500);
```

And then after that animation I want the scroll to start from the bottom so that I can when the user starts scrolling move the drawer back down again by the amount of pixels a user has scrolled up.

Comment: Try `$("html,body").scrollTop(800)`. I think window scrollTop doesn't work on all browsers.

Comment: so. you want on page load the screen to scroll automatically to 800 px down ?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want, or to the bottom of the vh, 800 was just a number that I used for testing bottom of the view is what I really want

Comment: please add generated html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() < 92 ) {
        // if want to animate scroll
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("body, html").offset(800)
        }, 2000);
        // otherwise
        $("body, html").offset(800)
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but the values still remain the same. Could it be that the reason behind it is that the div with the top bar takes up 100vh, and the scrolling from the user is not possible in the first place?

Comment: place your html and css as well so that we can test practically

Answer (score 0):

I think you make a mistake，you should addEventListener to **window**,and when the page init, **window**'s **scrollTop()** eval **0**,so your second example can't work.and the last,when the browser inited the page,all of **console.log** had excuted,so you would see two same result by console.log,you can try to move on into **scroll function**,so you can see the scrollTop of window when mouse scroll.
there are some example for you:

```
console.log($(window).scrollTop());

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() < 92 && $(window).scrollTop() > -1) {
            $(window).scrollTop(800);
        }
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    });
```

the other one:

```
scrollDrawer = function () {
    if (1) {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() < 92 ) {
                $(window).scrollTop(800);
            }
        });
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    }
}
scrollDrawer();
```

Comment: I do call the scrollDrawer function from the other script where I animate the drawer to go up, after the animation I call the scrollDrawer() function

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it is something that can work with a little css.

```
var wrap = $("#wrap");

wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {

  if (this.scrollTop > 800) {
    wrap.addClass("new");
  } else {
    wrap.removeClass("new");
  }

});
```